# Spark DataFrame get all partitions using foreachPartition

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, partition

I have four partitions

```
                   /date/q1 
                        /q2
                        /q3
                        /q4
```

How to get each partition as DataFrame using foreachPartition.

Comment: `df.foreachPartition`?

Comment: Perhaps you could explain a little bit about what you are trying to accomplish?